# JS script not working properly after changing variable names

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a site for a customer. I've written some javascript that prints a list of links for the customer but it doesn't work like its supposed to. You can find the file [here](http://www.grizfirestarters.com/stores.js). Its supposed to print three columns but it only prints the first two. This used to work before before I changed some variable names. What could have gone wrong? See the finished page at grizfirestarters.com/stores_dyn.htm

EDIT: I've fixed the problem by making the column sizes set instead of dynamic. Kind of took the fun out of it, but gets the job done. code below:

```
/****************
Author: Timothy Grindall
Copyright: Timothy Grindall 2008

Note: the array "city_name_wash" is passed to this script by another script that is loaded on the same page and does not need to be included in this script.
Liscense: GNU Public Liscense. Note: if you don't know what the GNU public liscense is, you can probably find out by searching in Wikipedia at "http://www.wikipedia.org". A GNU Public Liscense basically means that you can use this code in any way you like as long as you don't sell the whole or any part of it in the original javascript or in a translated and/or compiled form.
*********************/

/**************************
*    format and print     *
**************************/

// *** Start Washington stores *** //

wash_col_size = Math.floor(city_name_wash.length / 3);

add_count = 2;

// calculate difference between rounded wash_col_size and unrounded wash_col_size. If there is a difference we need to compensate for extra cities/entries by making slightly longer columns

if ( (city_name_wash.length - (wash_col_size*3)) != 0 ) {
    wash_col_size = wash_col_size + add_count;
}

document.write("<div id='cities_wrapperL'>");//begin cities_wrapperL

for (i=0; i < wash_col_size*2; i++) {

    // prepare a link name from the city name
    link_name = city_name_wash[i].split(" (")[0]; // finds the first part of the name minus the "()"s on the end

    document.write("<div id='cityL'><a href='fixjava.htm' onclick='javascript: window.location = \"store_info_map.html?img=\" + this image + \"&city = " + link_name + "\"; return false;'> + city_name_wash[i] + "</ a></div>");

    i++; // increment counter

    // prepare a link name from the city name
    link_name = city_name_wash[i].split(" (")[0]; // finds the first part of the name minus the "()"s on the end

    document.write("<div id='cityC'><a href='fixjava.htm' onclick='javascript: window.location = \"store_info_map.html?img=\" + this_image + \"&city=" + link_name + "\"; return false;'>" + city_name_wash[i] + "</ a></div>");

}

document.write("</div><div id='cities_wrapperR'>"); // end of cities_wrapperL and start of cities_wrapperR


for ( i = wash_col_size*2; i < wash_col_size*3; i++){

    // prepare a link name from the city name
    link_name = city_name_wash[i].split(" (")[0]; // finds the first part of the name minus the "()"s on the end

    document.write("<div id='cityR'><a href='fixjava.htm' onclick = 'javascript: window.location = \"store_info_map.html?img = \" + this_image + \"&city = " + link_name + "\"; return false;'> + city_name_wash[i] + "</ a></div>");

}

document.write("</div>"); // end of cities_wrapperR

// *** start Idaho stores *** //


var content = document.getElementsByName("content")[0];
content.id = "short-back" + (wash_col_size - 3); // set to id that has the same positioning, but a different background image
if ( wash_col_size < 4 ) content.id = "short-back"; // in case there is three or less
if ( wash_col_size > 9 ) content.id = "main-content_stores"


/**************************
*     target example:     *
**************************/

/*
<div id="cities_wrapperL">
    <div id="cityL"><a href="Aberdeen.htm">Aberdeen</a></div>
    <div id="cityC"><a href="Gold Bar.htm">Gold Bar</a></div>
    <div id="cityL"><a href="Anacortes.htm">Anacortes</a></div>
    <div id="cityC"><a href="Granite_Falls.htm">Granite Falls</a></div>
    <div id="cityL"><a href="Arlington.htm">Arlington (2)</a></div>
    <div id="cityC"><a href="Hoodsport.htm">Hoodsport</a></div>
    <div id="cityL"><a href="Bellingham.htm">Bellingham (2)</a></div>
    <div id="cityC"><a href="Joyce.htm">Joyce (2)</a></div>
</div>
<div id="cities_wrapperR">
    <div id="cityR"><a href="Port_Angeles.htm">Port Angeles</a></div>
    <div id="cityR"><a href="Port_Townsend.htm">Port Townsend (2)</a></div>
    <div id="cityR"><a href="Poulsbo.htm">Poulsbo (2)</a></div>
    <div id="cityR"><a href="Randle.htm">Randle</a></div>
</div>
*/
```

Comment: Could you please include your code in the question itself instead of merely linking to it?

Comment: We're not going to dig your error from a SO-external code. Please add the code __relevant__ to your issue to the post, then we'll see ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This used to work before before I changed some variable names. What could have gone wrong?

just guessing, you stuffed up changing the variable names - change them back, then start again, or don't touch them again, depends on how you feel - looking at the code, it looks older than the 2008 copyright date, I'd recommend dragging the code kicking and screaming into the modern day

or, look at the **developer console** in any browser you prefer and see that line 45 has an undefined variable, namely `city_count`